# GITLAB CI with Docker and Software-Tests

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am currently trying to create a teststage for a deployment pipeline using a gitlab-ci.yml file. For this I have created a .NetCore test project in which various test scenarios run with xUnit.net and moq. From the project I create a Docker image, in which the project is built and then the tests run in the same image. A GitLab-Runner is used to create the Docker image. As a return value I get an xml file, in which is noted whether the tests were successful or not. The Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
COPY ["TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj", "TestWebApp/"]

RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
RUN dotnet restore "TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj"

COPY . . 

RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app 
RUN dotnet build "TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app 

FROM build AS test
RUN dotnet test "TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj" --logger "trx;LogFileName=webapplication1.xml" --results-directory /testresult; exit 0

FROM build AS publish 
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app 

FROM base AS final 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY --from=publish /app . 
COPY --from=test /testresult .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

The gitlab.ci.yml file  contains three stages:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deployment
```

The teststage in gitlab-ci.yml shalll only be successful, if within the xml-file  is written:
`<ResultSummary outcome="Passed">`

Now the problem is that I don't know how to get the testresults in the Docker container and be able to process them afterwards. I tried to access the xml file via the commands:

```
test:
  stage: test
  variables:
    ID: ${- docker-compose ps -q ${REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_REPO_NAME}:${DOCKER_TAG}}
  script:
    - docker run ${REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_REPO_NAME}:${DOCKER_TAG}
    - docker exec -it $ID /bin/bash
    - cat webapplication1_(?:[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})?(?:[_][0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})?(?:[-][0-9]{3})?.xml
```

Best regards regards and thanks for the help